Is ext4 and xfs only for usage with internal file systems?
I am attempting to store some large  files and I thought an encrypted ext4 partition would be excellent. However the GNOME Disk Utility appears to state ext4 as for internal disks and xfs only for Linux filesystems.
Can I utilize them both safely with removable media? Is there one that is more utilitarian for this usage? What makes them different?



Thank you so much for any information you can provide.

that wording internal disk for use with... in the GNOME window is poor antiquated wording.


Can I utilize them both safely with removable media?

Yes. The description in the user interface is concerned about compatibility with other operating systems rather than the mobility of the medium itself.

Is there one that is more utilitarian for this usage? What makes them different?

Most modern file-systems can store large files – depending on what you mean by "large": ext4 can store only up to 16 TiB while XFS supports 8 EiB. You can look up the details on tables like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits.
In regard to encryption: You can set-up an encrypted partition with LUKS. That is independent and will work with pretty much any file-system.
If you want encryption on the file-system level, you can use ext4 (the encryption feature is optional and considered experimental, but seems to work pretty well). You may consider a different file-system like ZFS. XFS does not offer encryption. Again, you can look this up in a table like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Block_capabilities.

Another thing to keep in mind is file ownership and permissions, if the removable medium is moved between machines.

add to it that owners are stored as a number. If user foo on system A is uid=1000, that same file might then show up on system B as property of user bar (which incidentally also has uid=1000 on that system).
Since Fat has no concept of users at all, the problem does not exist there. And NTFS has some sensible default users (which do not exist on Linux, the only common user-id is 0 for root, but you wouldn’t have all files on the exchange medium be property of root.

Since you need encryption, this doesn't really apply as you'll have to resort to a filesystem that supports it anyways.
But answering the question in a more general sense: beware that the fact that you could use them on removable media doesn't mean that you should use them on removable media. In fact, if you're planning on using the drive to quickly move files between different machines / expect to quickly be able to access the backups from different machines, I'd say forget about ext4.
Ext4, besides the issues with cross-platform compatibility (which may not be an issue if you're planning on using the drive just on Linux) is not "permissions-agnostic". Accessing the files on different machines with different users introduces problems with permissions that you need to sort out every time. For the use cases described above, it doesn't make too much sense to use ext4.
I usually go with exFAT for filesystems that need to carry stuff around, due to its extensive cross-platform support.

Linux supports idmapped mounts without FUSE, support for which could be added to UDisks to make all such mounts appear as if owned by the mounting user while storing UID 1000 or similar. (Actually I thought UDisks did add idmapped mount support recently?)

@u1686_grawity Do you mind expanding on the "id-mapped mounts without FUSE"? Do you mean a FUSE alternative? If it's something native you're talking about then I'm unfamiliar with that

No, I literally mean ID-mapping, nothing to do with FUSE at all (it just happens that earlier ID-mapping solutions had to use FUSE). If you have a very new util-linux version see "idmap" in man mount. (There's an older temporary "mount-idmapped" tool if you have a new kernel but old tools.) You can also find it mentioned in e.g. systemd-nspawn's docs where it's used for containers.

@u1686_grawity Ah yes, I think I've known that at some point but for some reason I completely forgot everything about that. And I still use FUSE mounts everywhere... Thanks for bringing that up, I removed the FUSE mention as it was tangential anyways
